Can I choose whatever variable I want for $F$ when using d'Alembert's formula in PDEs?
I have the following PDE and initial conditions:
$$\begin{cases}
u_{tt}-u_{xx}=\cos\left(x\right)\\
u\left(x,0\right)=\sin\left(x\right)\\
u_{t}\left(x,0\right)=1+x
\end{cases}$$
plugging everything into the formula we get:
$$u\left(x,t\right)=\frac{\sin\left(x+t\right)+\sin\left(x-t\right)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\intop_{x-t}^{x+t}1+s\,ds+\frac{1}{2}\intop_{0}^{t}\intop_{x-\left(t-\tau\right)}^{x+\left(t-\tau\right)}\cos\left(\tau\right)d\eta\,d\tau$$
now in the double integral I chose $\cos (x)$ to be with the variable of $\tau$ instead of $\eta$, am I allowed to do that? my reasoning is that since $F(x,t)$ only depends on $x$ I can choose whichever variable ($\tau$ or $\eta$) to be the variable of $F(x)$

Correct is $\frac{1}{2} \int _0^t\int _{x-(t-\tau )}^{x+(t-\tau )}\cos (\eta )d\eta d\tau$

@gpmath are you saying this as a sort of rule of thumb? because I've just done the integrals in both ways and I found 2 different functions $u(x,t)$ that satisfy the problem.
$$u\left(x,t\right)=\left(\sin\left(x\right)-\cos\left(x\right)\right)\cos\left(t\right)+\cos\left(x\right)+xt+t$$ and $$u\left(x,t\right)=\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(t\right)+xt+t+1-\cos\left(t\right)$$

Let
\begin{align}
u_1(x,t)&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\int_{x-(t-\tau)}^{x+(t-\tau)}\cos(\tau)\,d\eta d\tau \\
&=\int_0^t\cos(\tau)(t-\tau)\,d\tau 
=1-\cos(t) \tag{1}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
u_2(x,t)&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\int_{x-(t-\tau)}^{x+(t-\tau)}\cos(\eta)\,d\eta d\tau \\
&=\int_0^t\cos(x)\sin(t-\tau)\,d\tau 
=\cos(x)[1-\cos(t)].\phantom{\int_0^t} \tag{2}
\end{align}
Notice that $(\partial_t^2-\partial_x^2)u_1(x,t)=\cos(t)$ and $(\partial_t^2-\partial_x^2)u_2(x,t)=\cos(x)$. Therefore, the correct option is $(2)$, as pointed out by gpmath.

I see, thank you!
